# How to auto increment the id of an parameter in angular typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a gallery using  `@ks89/angular-modal-gallery` and all that remains to be done is giving different ids to gallery.
I tried with a for loop but it gives me undefined..

[image]

**page1.ts**

```
getAllPosts() {
    this.authService.getAllPosts().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res: any) => {

      const ress = res;
      console.log(ress);

      this.getFullPosts = res.data.post;
      this.personSubject.next(res.data.post)

      this.userGallery = res.data.post.forEach(img => {
        img.galleryImages = img.images.map(image => {

          console.log(image.lenght)
          return new Image(
           id:  //here i have to pass the id for each gallery,
            {
              img: image,
              extUrl: image,
              title: image,

            })



        });
      });

    
    });

  }
```

**Image.ts**

```
export declare class Image {
    id: number;
    modal: ModalImage;
    plain?: PlainImage;
    constructor(id: number, modal: ModalImage, plain?: PlainImage);
}
```

Comment: you just looking to add any number to id: ? but that should be unique?

Comment: I have to create as many galleries as users i have in post.. So each gallery by its class has an parameter called id , other than that from the ngfor in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use map, or forEach or find over an array you can use an additional paramenter, the index (the first is 0)

```
img.galleryImages = img.images.map(
    (image:any,index:number)=>new Image({id:index,...image})
)
```

But, really Check if is necesary the "id" in your gallery or not. In Angular generally it's not necesary in a *ngFor have differents ids